# Error rolling back sql file created in Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2.3.0, backup

When I try to rollback using a sql dump file created in Magento 2.3.0, I get the following error:

`Table 'inventory_stock_1' was not locked with LOCK TABLES`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because I spent all morning on this and thought it might be helpful to someone else.

The issue is that with 2.3.0 `inventory_stock_1` is no longer a table, it's now a view. That's all fine except that the code creating the sql backup still wants to treat it like a table. Hopefully this gets fixed in the next version.

My fix was to directly edit the sql dump file using a text editor. The entire block related to this table, starting from this line:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `inventory_stock_1`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventory_stock_1`;
```

all the way to this line:

```
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `inventory_stock_1` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

It all needs to be replaced with a create view query instead. Delete all those lines, and in their place include:

```
CREATE
OR REPLACE
VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS select
    distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
    `product`.`sku` AS `sku`
from
    ( `cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on
        (( `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id` )));
```

Save the dump file and try the rollback again.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This happened to us after a move. Also remember to do a full product & stock reindex to also remove the last ".. definer/invoker of view lack rights .." error on the inventory_stock_1 view...